# C# decoding non Ascii characters?

Tags: c#, decode, encode, non-ascii-characters

I am reading a meta description from couple of sites using HtmlAgilityPack.

I noticed if it is not English letters it does not decode the special characters. (such as Japaneses letters).

I am using Encoding UTF8 - should I be using something else.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(item.Attributes["content"].Value);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Encoding.Default` at all? Also why are you not just doing `return item.Attributes["content"].Value;`?

Comment: if I do just return item.Attributes["content"].Value;then it displays not Japaneses letters. shows something like: �v���̌��R�~���� @ScottChamberlain

Comment: How are you displaying it? Show that code. Also check the `string` object returned by `Value` see if it has the correct values in it by inspecting the string in the debugger. If it does not have the correct values it you need to go back further and figure out why `item` is not parsing whatever your data source is correctly.

Comment: Could you show some code about how you get  `item` with 
Html Agility Pack. And what happends when you change `Encoding.Default/Encoding.UTF8` to :  `Encoding.Unicode` in both lines

Comment: please edit your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something we can copy and paste in to our own visual studio and see the problem happen too. You should be able to do it within 20 or so lines if you use a simplified data source from a string instead of pulling it from a html file off the internet.

Comment: I have checked the string in  the debugger and it does not have the correct values. The sites I am pulling the tag description are live. I am using WebClient . DownloadString(website url) to ready the meta description and then I load content into HtmlDocument using LoadHtml method. If this is confusing and you think it is related to the issue i can update my question with the code I am doing. Thank you

Comment: Your bug is likely in the *"I am using WebClient . DownloadString(website url) to ready the meta description and then I load content into HtmlDocument using LoadHtml method."* section. That is why I asked for a Miniml Complete Verifiable Example. You should create the smallest program possible that re-creates the problem and post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, seems like your website is using SHIFT-JIS encoding, not UTF-8. I've added two samples for UTF-8 and SHIFT-JIS.

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // UTF-8
            var content = client.DownloadString("http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/");
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(content);
            var metaDescNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name=\"description\"]");
            var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(metaDescNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
            var decodedMetaDesc = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // This string has decoded characters

            // Shift_JIS
            var japaneseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(932); 
            var content2 = client.DownloadString("http://www.toronto-electricians.com/");
            var doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
            doc2.LoadHtml(content2);
            var metaDescNode2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name=\"description\"]"); 
            var bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(metaDescNode2.Attributes["content"].Value);
            var decodedMetaDesc2 = japaneseEncoding.GetString(bytes2); // This string has decoded characters
        }
```

Screenshot #1 from debugger.

[image]

Screenshot #2 from debugger.

[image]

Comment: your code does work.. with the site you used in the sample. I have tried with a different website `http://www.toronto-electricians.com/`and shows the �v���̌��R�~��� . Can you run your code with my site. Does it show okay for you?

Comment: Ah! Your site uses "Shift_JIS" charset, let me update my code.

Comment: @Ben see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks so much Ignas. It works! Please correct me if I am wrong: Shift_JIS or UTF-8 ..or others.. does this mean the format of the characters that represent the text? My application will be dealing with different websites. Do you think it is safe to modify to  `Encoding.GetEncoding(doc.DeclaredEncoding.CodePage)` this way it will get the correct type for specific website?

Comment: You are correct, encodings are like mappings to map characters into sequences of bytes.
`doc.DeclaredEncoding.CodePage` looks like a nice solution, however be aware of (A) some sites may not declare it or declare in a format that `HtmlAgilityPack` might not understand, and (B) in some rare cases declaration might be different from an actual encoding.

Comment: appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient.DownloadString is a limited, high-level method which makes it awkward and error-prone to do fundamentally simple things.

Fetching a web page via HTTP is simple. You give a URL and some request headers; The server responds with some response headers and a byte stream of the body. The response headers typically state the character encoding of a text body. If not, the text body might say itself. HTMLAgilityPack understands this and provides the HtmlWeb class to do create an HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument from that interaction.

```
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/");
var keywords = document.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='keywords']")
    .Attributes["content"]?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(keywords);
Console.WriteLine($@"
  StreamEncoding:   {document.StreamEncoding?.EncodingName}
  DeclaredEncoding: {document.DeclaredEncoding?.EncodingName}
  Encoding:         {document.Encoding?.EncodingName}");
```

---

```
NHK,ニュース,NHK NEWS WEB

  StreamEncoding:   Unicode (UTF-8)
  DeclaredEncoding: 
  Encoding:         Unicode (UTF-8)
```

Comment: I have tried running your code with using url: `http://www.toronto-electricians.com/` SHIFT-JIS encoding and it doesnt work, returns �̉���グ��

Comment: @Ben I'm stumped for the moment. I did put your page through the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.toronto-electricians.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&fbc=1&doctype=Inline&fbd=1&group=1&ss=1&outline=1&No200=1&verbose=1) and it fails at being XHTML. But nothing jumps out at me that would cause HtmlAgilityPack to mangle characters.

Comment: @Ben, it's hard to parse the layered specifications, but your server is sending an HTTP Content-Type header without a charset declaration. An HTTP Content-Type header with a charset declaration definitely would override any HTML/XHTML meta charset declaration. With the header present but the charset missing, perhaps the override is taking place with a default of UTF-8. Can you change the server to include the charset in the Content-Type header?